# 2 Cycle Blower Primer Bulb Not Filling

Tags: gas, blower, engine

I have the Ryobi BP42 back pack blower and when I press the primer bulb it does not fill up with the gas/oil mix.  I have checked the air filter (and yes it does look dirty), ordered a new one and have removed the hoses from the gas tank.  If I press the primer bulb, the hose connected to it does suck in air.

The second hose that connects to the carburetor, I have also disconnected and cleaned and am able to blow through it so I know there is no blockage in that hose either.

I reconnected all parts, and when I press the primer button still the bulb does not fill with the mix.  I can press in the bulb and it sinks in, and then slowly pops back out just as it should, but there is no flow of gas/oil coming to the bulb.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Other than that...  Does the engine run?

Comment: @Harper -> I was using it and it cut off on me with roughly 1/4 tang of mix left.  Have had no probs up until this happened.  So I would be inclined to say yes....when it cut out on me, it sounded as if it had run out of gas, just kind of got lower and lower and lower until it cut out

Comment: ok next question, did you notice it doing this thing with teh bulb before?  I wonder if it's unrelated.  Was the gas properly premixed? (same gas you'd beeen using all along yes?)

Comment: The primer bulb issue first started after the blower cut off.  Yes, same gas/oil mix as I had been running before.